# How to create a custom iterator in kotlin and add to existing class?

Tags: kotlin, for-loop, iterator

Hello I am trying to add a custom iterator for example to a Pair class from kotlin package to be able to use instance of that class in a for loop

Let's assume this is what I want to be able to do:

```
val pair: Pair<Int, String> = Pair(1, "sample data")
for (element in pair) {
println(element)
}
```

I know that there are plenty other ways to print elements from a pair but I specifically want to be able to use pair in a for loop and I need to add iterator() object with next() and hasNext() methods implementation to Pair class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by providing the `iterator()` operator for your object, either as a member function or extension function. Example using an extension function:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val pair: Pair<Int, String> = Pair(1, "sample data")
    for (element in pair) {
        println(element)
    }
}

operator fun <T> Pair<T, T>.iterator(): Iterator<T> = listOf(first, second).iterator()
```

However, you need to be aware that this way you partially lose strongly typing. `element` can only be a common supertype of all elements, in most cases simply `Any?`.

You can read more about this in the official documentation: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/control-flow.html#for-loops

Comment: thank you, Sir. Can you also explain why we need to specify <T> before Pair in the operator fun? And how to use member function in this case, when Pair is a class from kotlin package?

Comment: We can't add member functions to 3rd party classes - in this case you have to use extensions, as above. As a matter of fact, this is one of the main reasons for introducing extensions - to make possible to extend 3rd party types. `<T>` allows to use `Pair` with arbitrary types: it will work as expected with `Pair<String, String>` and with `Pair<Int, Int>`. If you don't know what are generics or parameterized types, then this is much longer topic and can't be explained in just few sentences. Read about generics in Kotlin (but you may need to start with generics in Java).

Comment: Thanks, I just thought Pair<T,T> should be enough.